# Как найти общие вершины двух правильных многоугольников?

Tags: python, алгоритм, геометрия, теория-чисел

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту задачу. Что-то совсем не могу понять как это можно реализовать..

В окружность вписаны N-угольник и M-угольник. Известно, что многоугольники правильные и имеют как минимум одну общую вершину. Вам необходимо подсчитать, сколько всего общих вершин имеют эти два многоугольника.

Ввод:

4 6

Вывод:

2

Comment: Вроде бы такой вариант не проходит проверку. Я ввожу 4, 6, мне должно вывести 2, а выводит 1

Comment: А, ну да, Общие делители искать надо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно так.
Исходя из того, что многоугольник правильный, он разделит окружность, в которую вписан, на равные дуги. Остается найти "градусы", в которых угол многоульника накладывается на окружность, а потом посчитать совпадения для 2х многоульников.

```
N = 4
M = 6

N_set = set(i*360/N for i in range(N))
M_set = set(i*360/M for i in range(M))

print(len(N_set.intersection(M_set)))
```

---

Или можно просто найти НОД.

Comment: Самое ужасное что этот код работает. Хотя то что он работает - жуткое везение. Так писать нельзя. Вы сравниваете вещественные числа на равенство, даже не понимая почему в результате приближенных вычислений получается точное равенство.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вообще я прекрасно понимаю, что сравнить вещ. числа не есть хорошо. Потому и написал еще одну идею решения, которая будет более верной.

Comment: Вы этот код показываете человеку с весьма поверхностными знаниями в программировании. Код рабочий. Человек получает подтверждение что с вещественными числами можно что угодно делать а потом сравнивать. Следующий этап: "почему `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3`"?

Answer (score 3):

Ответом является `НОД(n, m)`.

Возьмём отрезок `[0, nm)`. Отложим на нём от нуля две арифметические прогрессии. Одна с шагом `m`, вторая - `n`. Сколько у них общих точек?

Пусть `x` - общая точка. Тогда `x` делится и на `n` и на `m`. Следовательно `x` делится на `НОК(n, m)`.

И наоборот, любая точка вида `k НОК(n, m)` является общей.

Точек вида `k НОК(n, m)` на отрезке `[0, nm)` ровно `nm / НОК(n, m)`. Это отношение равно `НОД(n, m)`.

Задача была про математику, не про программирование:

```
import math

n = 4
m = 6

print(math.gcd(n, m))
```